# id for simpleType

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to xml.

I want to store a list of keywords in an XML document. I also need an ID to assign the keywords to articles that will be stored in the XML, too. I will then use the IDREF

Until now I have the following XSD:

```
<complexType name="keywordList">
    <sequence>
        <element name="keyword" 
              type="tns:tag" 
              minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<simpleType id="ID" name="tag">
    <restriction base="string">
        <minLength value="1"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>

  <element name="keywords" type="tns:keywordList"></element>
```

And the following test XML:

```
<dss:keywords xmlns="http://dss.in.tum.de/" xmlns:dss="http://dummy"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://dummy dummy.xsd >
    <dss:keyword id="K1">testing</dss:keyword>
    <dss:keyword id="k2">requirements</dss:keyword>
    <dss:keyword id="k3">modelling</dss:keyword>
    <dss:keyword id="k4">implementation</dss:keyword>
</dss:keywords>
```

Unfortunately I have the following validation error for the `id-values`:

> cvc-type.3.1.1: Element 'dss:keyword' is a simple type, so it cannot
>   have attributes, excepting those whose namespace name is identical to
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' and whose [local name] is
>   one of 'type', 'nil', 'schemaLocation' or 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation'.
>   However, the attribute, 'id' was found.   dummy.xml   /HelloWorld

What could be the reason for such error?

Comment: `keyword` must be a complex type.Only complex types can have attributes.

Comment: It would be a complex type with simple content.